Capitalization and Use of Acronyms?
When examining algorithms like the Decision Tree Classifier, should it be capitalized as "Decision Tree Classifier (DTC)" or written in lowercase as "decision tree classifier (DTC)"? When I refer to a specific algorithm, for example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html
I am uncertain whether it should be treated as a proper noun. For example, when stating "we used the Decision Tree Classifier (DTC)" should it be capitalized? Since the DTC can denote a class of algorithms and might not refer to a unique entity, it might not qualify as a proper noun. However, if it specifically refers to the linked algorithm, does it become a proper noun and should thus be capitalized as "Decision Tree Classifier"?
Similarly, if one were to develop a new algorithm or classifier, such as "Cool New Classifier (CNC)," would this not also be considered a proper noun, necessitating capitalization?
I am also particularly confused by the inconsistent capitalization of "Internet of Things" across various articles.
Furthermore, when mentioning or referencing a newly introduced framework, "Some New Framework (SNF)," should it be capitalized since I specifically refer to that framework? For example this one: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/372285194_SEFWaM-deep_learning_based_smart_ensembled_framework_for_waste_management
If someone could maybe tell me how to handle this, I would be very happy.
Edit: so my question got closed, because it "seems similar" to this article here: Proper capitalization of commonly used acronyms and initialisms
But where is then the answer to my questions in this article?
I am still confused. Why got my question closed, what is similar?

Does this answer your question? Proper capitalization of commonly used acronyms and initialisms Note that many authorities now reserve the term 'acronym' for abbreviations that are read as if a single word (NATO); BBC, DTC etc are called 'initialisms'.

Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question.

'There is no universal rule; the Guardian's style guide is just one set of rules you can choose. The important thing is to be consistent.' answers your question.  Acronym Finder lists around 100 expansions of DTC but does not include 'decision tree classifier'. So there is no standard usage here. But every one of the listings of the initialism DTC it does recognise is capitalised.

"You pays your money and you takes your choice."
If you believe in "vox populi, vox dei" then you will be impressed by the Google Ngram of Decision Tree Classifier,decision tree classifier, which shows a recent marked preference for the capitalised version.
